# Sending and Receiving files in XMPP bot with Python

Tags: python, xmpp, bots

I'm using the following bot (based on [xmppy](http://xmpppy.sourceforge.net/)):

```
import xmpp, os

user = 'uname'
password = 'pass'
server="talk.google.com"

def message_handler(connect_object, message_node): 
        messageFromCounterPart = message_node.getBody()
        connect_object.send( xmpp.Message( message_node.getFrom() ,message_node.getBody()))


jid = xmpp.JID(user) 
connection = xmpp.Client(jid.getDomain()) 
connection.connect(server = (server, 5223)) 
result = connection.auth(jid.getNode(), password, "LFY-client") 
connection.RegisterHandler('message', message_handler) 
connection.sendInitPresence()     
while connection.Process(1): 
    pass
```

How to cause it to receive and send files? Is there special name for stanzas in this case? (like in `connection.RegisterHandler('message', message_handler)`)
Thanks.

Comment: You should label the xmpp lib you used.

Comment: dumplicated with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2851992/how-can-i-transfer-a-file-via-xmpp-using-python